# How do I recharge this pressure pump?

Tags: water-pressure

The plumber is a notorious no show for days if not weeks and I would like some water pressure. Not to mention being self-sufficient.

Here is a photo of the pressure pump.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2JPE.jpg

Comment: Link to manual: http://www.amtrol.com/media/documents/pressure_booster/9040B140_04_11_MC8710_Pressuriser_IO.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by "recharge"? Do you think you need to re-prime the pump? Does the pump run when you open the tap and leave it open for a while?

Comment: The pump was working, and then the tank supply it ran dry. I refilled the tank, but now the pump does not pressurize the water.

Comment: I have re-read that manual 10 times and it ceases to be any clearer how to do it.

Comment: Does the pump try to run? Or does it never come on?

Comment: It hums and clicks then shuts off.

Comment: The pump does not appear to be appropriate for pumping water from a holding tank;  certainly not one that can run dry...or where the surface of the holding tank is less that about 20 feet above the pump...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To borrow what [User58220](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/15822/user58220) said, I think part of your problem here is that you have the wrong pump for your application. This pump is designed to boost the incoming water pressure from a municipal water service. It requires a minimum of 10 psi to function correctly. The rule of thumb is 1 psi for every 2 feet of elevation, so you will need to elevate your tank at least 20 feet above the pump. If you can't, then hire a competent plumber to install the proper type of pump.

Provided you do have at least 10 psi, next you should check the controller. Hold the square button down until the display says `Lo`. Make a note of the number that appears after a few seconds. Press the square button twice. It will either display an error code or `--`. Consult the manual if you have an error.

The final thing to check is the pressure tank. Turn off the pump, turn off the water from the tank, and open (and leave open) a faucet to relieve the pressure. Then find the air stem (should look like the fill valve on a tire) and read the pressure. This number should be about 2 psi less than the `Lo` number you noted previously. If the pressure is incorrect, then let some air out or pump some air in until you are 2 psi below the `Lo` number.

If the tank leaks water out of the air stem when you try to take a pressure reading, then the pressure bladder in the tank is ruptured or water-logged. Replace the tank.

Comment: Thank you for the walk through. 

The tank is above the pressurizer, some feet up a hill. The tank is connected to municipal water, but there was a break in the pump that fed the tank.

I held the square button and got : 50 
The error message is : E2

I turned everything off, checked the pressure, it said 28.

Comment: When ON and IDLE, the digital readout displays a number that fluctuates between 11 and 15.

Comment: It sounds like you have a bad pressure tank. Did you check it?

Comment: I ended up calling Amtrol Tech Support with the info I gained from your answer. They said it sounded like a burnt up motor due to the auto-shutoff failing. I put my local distributor in contact with them and am waiting to hear back. But it should be covered by my warranty.